# I'm comparing two sentences. What version of these sentences looks Ok for you?

Tags: grammar, word-usage, sentence, syntactic-analysis, construction

Please compare two sentences. Which version is correct?

1)"This place is an opportunity to take a rest in THE uniqueness OF THE local nature where you can feel Russian hospitality."

2)"You will have an opportunity to take a rest in the uniqueness of the local nature enjoying Russian hospitality. (Can I write “where you can feel Russian hospitality” instead?)"

Can I write: "in the uniqueness of the local nature"?

Is number 1 not correct? What about the second version? Its meaning, grammar, articles, the usage "of" in a sense of belonging to something?

Thank you.

Comment: Without having time at the moment to figure out the better phrasing, I can at least let you know they're both wrong.

Comment: “nature” typically refers to animals, plants, trees, mountains, rivers etc.  but not people and cultures.  If Russian hospitality is like leaving you alone in nature, then ok we could start to work on your grammar- if that weren’t off topic.

Comment: @Jim *Nature* is certainly used for people and cultures, just not when left by itself. *Someone's nature* is how they're put together and how they act, *someplace's nature* is its characteristic features; it's just that left alone *nature* is the characteristic feature of everything, which is, y'know, nature.

Comment: @lly - Fair enough.  That’s a different nature than is being discussed here though.

Comment: @Jim It's the same word and the use she's thinking of. She just needs to know that it has to be qualified somehow or it defaults to being nature-of-all-things-in-general.

Comment: In any case, one way to rewrite the sentence would be *Our facilities provide an opportunity to relax in Sevastopol's unique environment while enjoying Russian hospitality*... where Sevastopol can be replaced by Wherevergrad. That said, at least in English-speaking countries, Russians are famous for their stoic resolve and livers, not so much for their hospitality to strangers or even customers. You might leave that phrasing off, unless you know you have a Russophile customer base.

Comment: Thank you, guys, for all your comments! They are very helpful.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Don't use the word **uniqueness**, especially in this context. I don't really know much about what you are writing, but there are certain words that are never going to sound good when read aloud or in one's head. This is one of those words. (Other examples might be 'being', 'stupider')

"Hospitality" and "nature" are unrelated, in a manner of speaking.

You don't usually want to describe a place as an opportunity. "Opportunity" seems to be more often associated with temporal windows rather than physical locations.

A better version of this sentence might look like:

```
(T)here, you can take solace in the natural beauty of the Russian landscape.
```

Comment: @Anastasia There's nothing wrong with *being*. The problem is that people new to English treat it as a standard verb instead of a stative one and overuse it. There's nothing wrong with *uniqueness*, but it doesn't fit here since it's impossible to rest within something's state of being unique. Again, nothing wrong with the word; it just gets misused as a synonym for things it isn't a synonym of.